# how to create a variable name by appending run time data

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I am trying to create a variable run time by appending some value.

example:-

```
def one(num):
    "var"+num+"one" = "hi"
    "var"+num+"two" = "hello"
    "var"+num+"three" = "bye"
    print(var1one)
    print(var1two)
    print(var1three)
    
one("1")
```

Explanation:-
here I am passing run time data as string ("1") and within function I am trying to create variable  with the name
myvar, one
myvar, two
myvar, three
and trying to append function argument here "1" so later I should be able to print by  myvar1one, myvar1two and myvar1three.

So, Kindly help me how can I achieve this.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't do this. Instead, just use a dictionary: `myvar = {}`. Then `myvar[num] = "I'm variable " + num`.

Comment: Hi @Carcigenicate will it work if we add another part for variable name like
myvar + num  + anothermyvar= "I'm variable " + num
print(myvar1anothermyvar)

Comment: You can make the dictionary key whatever string you want.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I rewrite my question please have a look once and help me to get solution for this.

Comment: Same answer. `myvar = {}`, `myvar[num] = "hi"`, `print(myvar[num])`.